# PostgreSQL: Merge rows with the same date and time but different numeric values in one row with average of the values

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a financial software where we have huge table of ticks with more than 800M rows.

A single row: `symbol_id, broker_id, date, time, bid, ask`

The problem is the table has many ticks with identical first four columns and different `bid` and `ask`.

What is the best way to update the table and combine such rows into one by taking an average of `bid` and `ask` columns?

Example:

`|1|2|2012-01-01|12:00:00|1.3456|1.3678|`

`|1|2|2012-01-01|12:00:00|1.3463|1.3612|`

Result row:

`|1|2|2012-01-01|12:00:00|1.3459|1.3645|`

Comment: I think the quickest way would be to do a `create table as select ... ` using a group by, the drop the old table and rename the new one

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name is correct. @phil_g where is the primary key? Also you must put a trigger on the original table which updates the secondary average table, whenever a new insert is complete in the primary table. This is typically what they call upsert because a) it must put a new entry when the first four columns are encountered for the first time and update when the first four columns were encountered in the primary table.

Comment: @Alexandros thanks for the replies. I've tried the method on a slice of the table and it really works. It is my first database-involving project larger than 'creating a blog', so I've read many different articles and somehow decided that I do not need a PK for that table (it has indices though). All need is to keep countless number of ticks, requesting data for various periods.

Comment: @Alexandros A trigger like that will be murder on performance - it'll serialize all inserts on the base table, at least for any given set of keys, on the `UPDATE` lock held on a given aggregate record. Periodic re-aggregation will be much more efficient. You've also got to watch accumulated rounding errors when you repeatedly recalculate an average; better to store the sum and number of values and increment them, then return `sum/n` on the fly.

Comment: As the goal of merging is to make sure we have maximum one tick in one second, I think I came up with the easiest solution: creating a composite PK from `symbol_id, broker_id, date, time` and just ignore records with the same PK on `insert`.

Answer (score -3):

```
|1|2|2012-01-01|12:00:00|1.3459|1.3645|
```

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, AVG(col5) col5, AVG(col6) col6
FROM table_name
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4;
```